# Version control on Visual Studio SSIS project

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, tfvc

I am working on a visual studio integration service project (SSIS).
The edition of Visual Studio is Community Edition

What i want to do is to manage versioning (like source control for code)

I have tried to work with git. It works fine, i can commit changes.
But Integration Services Projects are not made of code: They are made with visual components.
I would like for example to run a "diff" command between 2 versions and show me clearly which components has changed between 2 revisions.

Git client is embedded in Visual Studio Community Edition but i can not run this kind of "diff".
Is there a way to do that with TFVC for example or another tool ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called BIDS Helper - [BI Developer Extensions](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/) which is a Visual Studio extension. Among its numerous features is a *"smart diff"* of SSIS files. It cleanses two SSIS files from its numerous generation GUIDs etc and compares component configuration.
Downside - you have to prepare two files yourself, the BIDS Helper is not integrated into Git or any other Source control client.